# How to set only first item active on while loop in php

Tags: php

i using slider fetch MYSQL records i using while function i need only active class in first item only. i need only active class in loop first element.how to solve this problem. i using this code but can't change the item.

mycode

```
<?php
                   $qry = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_type`='events' AND `post_event_start_date` <= CURDATE() ORDER BY `post_event_start_date`");
                   ?>
                    <?php while( $row = MYSQL_FETCH_OBJECT($qry) ){ ?>
                        <div class="item <?php if($i==0) { ?> active<?php } ?>">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="fff">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="administrator/slide_name/large/slide_1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 well">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <h3><?php print_r($row->post_title); ?></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <h4><?php print_r($row->post_url); ?></h4>
                                            <h5></h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <center><p>Start Date & Time</p><?php print_r($row->post_event_start_date); ?></center>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <center><p>Start End & Time</p><?php print_r($row->post_event_end_date); ?></center>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <p>Location:</p>
                                            <p><?php print_r($row->post_maplocation); ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <p>Description: </p>
                                            <p><?php print_r($row->post_desc); ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row pull-right">
                                            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Share it</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: out side $i=0; in while loop $i++ other code is ok

Comment: can you write code how to fix

Comment: please wait jst doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<?php while( $row = MYSQL_FETCH_OBJECT($qry) ){ ?>
<div class="item <?php if($i==0) { ?> active<?php } ?>">
```

With

```
   <?php
   $i=0;
   while( $row = MYSQL_FETCH_OBJECT($qry) ){ ?>
     <div class="item <?php if($i==0) { 
     $i=1;
     echo 'active'; } ?>">
```

Comment: Great !!  Happy coding! @AravinthE :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$qry = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM 'post' WHERE 'post_type'='events' AND 'post_event_start_date' <= CURDATE() ORDER BY 'post_event_start_date'");
 $first_item = true;?>
                    <?php while( $row = MYSQL_FETCH_OBJECT($qry) ){ ?>
                        <div class="item <?php echo $first_item? 'active': ''; ?>"><?php  $first_item = false; ?>
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="fff">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="administrator/slide_name/large/slide_1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 well">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <h3><?php print_r($row->post_title); ?></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <h4><?php print_r($row->post_url); ?></h4>
                                            <h5></h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <center><p>Start Date & Time</p><?php print_r($row->post_event_start_date); ?></center>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <center><p>Start End & Time</p><?php print_r($row->post_event_end_date); ?></center>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <p>Location:</p>
                                            <p><?php print_r($row->post_maplocation); ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <p>Description: </p>
                                            <p><?php print_r($row->post_desc); ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row pull-right">
                                            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Share it</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Define **$i = 0** and make it **$i++**
Try below code

```
 <?php
                       $qry = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_type`='events' AND `post_event_start_date` <= CURDATE() ORDER BY `post_event_start_date`");
                       ?>
                        <?php 
        $i = 0;
    while( $row = MYSQL_FETCH_OBJECT($qry) ){ ?>
                            <div class="item <?php if($i==0) { ?> active<?php } ?>">
                            <ul class="thumbnails">
                                <li class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="fff">
                                        <div class="thumbnail">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="administrator/slide_name/large/slide_1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 well">

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <h3><?php print_r($row->post_title); ?></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <h4><?php print_r($row->post_url); ?></h4>
                                                <h5></h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                        <center><p>Start Date & Time</p><?php print_r($row->post_event_start_date); ?></center>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                        <center><p>Start End & Time</p><?php print_r($row->post_event_end_date); ?></center>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <p>Location:</p>
                                                <p><?php print_r($row->post_maplocation); ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <p>Description: </p>
                                                <p><?php print_r($row->post_desc); ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row pull-right">
                                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Share it</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                           $i++;
                         } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $i = 0 ;
$qry = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_type`='events' AND `post_event_start_date` <= CURDATE() ORDER BY `post_event_start_date`");
?>
<?php while( $row = MYSQL_FETCH_OBJECT($qry) ){ ?>
<div class="item <?php if($i==0) { ?> active<?php } ?>">
Your other code
php $i++; } ?>
```